# Extracting x and y values from a character string in R

Tags: r, for-loop, character

I'm completely new to R. I have a dataframe which which contains the character below:

[{\"task\":\"T1\",\"task_label\":\"Draw around the infarct area\n\",\"value\":[{\"tool\":0,\"frame\":0,\"points\":[{\"x\":786,\"y\":139.8},{\"x\":712.3,\"y\":245.3},{\"x\":717.7,\"y\":291.7},{\"x\":804.9,\"y\":335.6},{\"x\":866.1,\"y\":352.7},{\"x\":877.5,\"y\":402.4},{\"x\":866,\"y\":492.9},{\"x\":823.2,\"y\":560.1},{\"x\":765.5,\"y\":603.6},{\"x\":791.8,\"y\":631.7},{\"x\":830.3,\"y\":617.8},{\"x\":846.9,\"y\":618.1},{\"x\":937.1,\"y\":538.5},{\"x\":941.1,\"y\":476.4},{\"x\":983.2,\"y\":443},{\"x\":1020.5,\"y\":338.4},{\"x\":997.1,\"y\":232.7},{\"x\":996.9,\"y\":232.7},{\"x\":921.5,\"y\":145},{\"x\":921.2,\"y\":145},{\"x\":850.6,\"y\":121},{\"x\":850.6,\"y\":120.7},{\"x\":786,\"y\":139.8}],\"details\":[],\"tool_label\":\"Tool name\"}]}]"

I am looking to extract the x and y coordinates and index them. For example:

x1 = 786, x2 = 712.3, x3 = 717.7 etc

y1 = 139.8, y2 = 245.3, y3 = 291.7 etc

I have tried using substring and gsub but have got unstuck.

Ideally, I would create a for loop which reads the number and stores as a variable.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like a json structure. Only precondition: remove the `\n` character "Draw around the infarct area\n". Then this worked on my system.

```
require(jsonlite)
dt <- fromJSON("[{\"task\":\"T1\",\"task_label\":\"Draw around the infarct area\",\"value\":[{\"tool\":0,\"frame\":0,\"points\":[{\"x\":786,\"y\":139.8},{\"x\":712.3,\"y\":245.3},{\"x\":717.7,\"y\":291.7},{\"x\":804.9,\"y\":335.6},{\"x\":866.1,\"y\":352.7},{\"x\":877.5,\"y\":402.4},{\"x\":866,\"y\":492.9},{\"x\":823.2,\"y\":560.1},{\"x\":765.5,\"y\":603.6},{\"x\":791.8,\"y\":631.7},{\"x\":830.3,\"y\":617.8},{\"x\":846.9,\"y\":618.1},{\"x\":937.1,\"y\":538.5},{\"x\":941.1,\"y\":476.4},{\"x\":983.2,\"y\":443},{\"x\":1020.5,\"y\":338.4},{\"x\":997.1,\"y\":232.7},{\"x\":996.9,\"y\":232.7},{\"x\":921.5,\"y\":145},{\"x\":921.2,\"y\":145},{\"x\":850.6,\"y\":121},{\"x\":850.6,\"y\":120.7},{\"x\":786,\"y\":139.8}],\"details\":[],\"tool_label\":\"Tool name\"}]}]")
(dt[[3]][[1]])[[3]][[1]]
```

If you want to remove the `\n`characters with code you could use a function like `str_replace` in the `stringr` package.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jan points out, this is JSON data. But I think it's probably easier to get the data out with regular expressions.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
str_extract_all(data,'([xy])[\\\":]+([0-9\\.]+)') %>%
  str_extract_all(c("[xy]","[0-9\\.]+")) %>%
  bind_cols
# A tibble: 46 x 2
   V1    V2   
   <chr> <chr>
 1 x     786  
 2 y     139.8
 3 x     712.3
 4 y     245.3
 5 x     717.7
 6 y     291.7
 7 x     804.9
 8 y     335.6
 9 x     866.1
10 y     352.7
# … with 36 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks - really helpful. 

With the code "str_extract_all(c("[xy]","[0-9\\.]+")) %>%" I get the message: 

"Error in type(pattern) : argument "pattern" is missing, with no default"

Any idea how to correct this? Thanks